# Unbind queue from exchange in AMQP Spring XML?

Tags: grails, spring-amqp

Is there a way to declaratively unbind a queue from an exchange in a Spring XML file?

I attempted this based on a result from ChatGPT but the "unbind-queue" element doesn't event exist, apparently.

`<rabbit:unbind-queue queue-name="xxxxxxx" exchange-name="xxxx" routing-key="#" />`

Answer (score 0):

May we see your request to ChatGPT? I wonder why did it give you so misleading information.

What purpose such a declaration would bring to Spring application context if that would exist?

You can perform such an operation manually in an administrative way using `RabbitAdmin` API. But declarative way does not bring any value for application context. It is an overengeniring to try to bring everything into the XML configuration.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have it but I do recall that it said to use rabbit:unbind-queue, which doesn't exist. I replied to that effect and it agreed with me.

In any event, since writing this I have used AmqpAdmin to do this; however, I need to access the XML file so I can parse it and iterate over the exchanges/queues within it. It's located in grails-app/conf/spring but I'm not sure how to load and parse it. Or perhaps there's a way to do it that's more straightfowards?

Comment: OK. Let's step back and see what is your business task. The logic you are asking is an absurd from the XML configuration perspective: the XML is for config not for programming logic. You declare some configuration which turns via Spring parsers to beans at runtime. For example, you declare RabbitMQ queue and `RabbitAdmin`. When the application context is ready, the last one tries to create and bind the first. What kind of bean definition would you expect from an `unbind()` method call?

Comment: Artem, thank you for your frank assessment. Understand that I am completely new to all of this, i.e., Groovy, Grails, RabbitMQ, etc. In any event, I was able to use SpEL and some logic in bootstrap to accomplish what I needed to do which was to either unbind an drain the classic queues or create new quorum queues and destroy the old classic queues after they've drained based upon a application configuration settings.

Comment: Sounds good! So, now you understand that XML is just a configuration instructions set. The `if...else` or so logic must be done in the real programming language.